# A complex number $z$ satisfies $|z - i| = |z|$ and $\arg\left(\dfrac{z}{z - i}\right) = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$. Then $\text{Re}(2z - 1)$ equals?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have almost completed my mock test syllabus, but complex numbers are pretty complicated for me. Can anyone give me some tips to approach this kind of problem? There are tons of questions like this in the previous year's papers.

Please don't downvote me, I just want a tip to improve in these kind of problems

Comment: May be you can translate the question into geometry on the complex plane? For example, as a first step, $z-i$ is a point one unit _lower_ on the plane than the original $z$, and $|z-i|$ and $|z|$ are distances of $z-i$ and $z$ from the origin $O$. How would you describe the positions of $z,$ $z-i$ and $O$ relative to each other based on that distances' equality? What would it tell you about $z$?

Comment: You need to *recognize* some standard forms here. The first equation is a perpendicular bisector of two points, and the second is a part-circle. You can either draw a picture or express each equation in Cartesian form

Comment: @DavidQuinn That's right - provided that OP has been taught recognizing them.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Express complex number $z$ in standard form, i.e. $z=x+iy$, $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Now, we have

\begin{aligned}
\left| z-i \right| = \left| z \right| & \iff \left| x+yi-i \right| = \left| x+yi \right|\\ & \\ & \iff \sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\ & \\ & \iff -2y+1=0 \\ & \\ & \iff y=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}}.
\end{aligned}

Hint 2: Divide $z$ with $z-i \ldots$

Comment: 1/2 is the imaginary part, the question is to find the real part.

Comment: To @user376343: In original Q user asked for tips, not for complete solution.... BTW, $y$ is the imaginary part of $z$.